# Java SDK 11 + Java FX: javafx.stage.Stageにアクセスできません

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx

[この例](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven)を参考にして、Maven + Java SDK 11 + Java FX アプリを作ってみました。

**EntryPoint.java**

```
package com.example;

import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class EntryPoint extends javafx.application.Application {

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    launch();
  }

  public void start(Stage stage) {
    Label label = new Label("Hello, JavaFX11！");
    Scene scene = new Scene(label, 640, 480);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
  }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>Example</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-controls -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
      <version>11</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

コンパイルしない限り、IntellIJ IDEAの方からは警告がありません。コンパイルしてみると、このようなエラーが出ます：

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**JAVA_HOME**環境変数を設定してみました。効果ありません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

IntellIJ IDEAで適切なSDKが設定してあります：

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: エラーメッセージに「クラス・ファイルのバージョン54.0は不正です。52.0である必要があります。」とある事から、javafx-controls の jar ファイルに含まれるクラスファイルのバージョンは 54.0(Java 10 以上で実行可能)で、EntryPoint.java をコンパイルしようとしている javac コマンドのバージョンは Java 8 という事になります。

Comment: @metropolis コメント、ありがとうございます。・・・そうですか、IntelIJ IDEAでSDKバージョンを変えるだけ十分ではありませんね。javacを変える方法は直ぐ見当たらないので探しておきます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[リンク先のページ](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven)の[pom.xml](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/pom.xml)にある以下の要素を省いているのが、原因ではないでしょうか。

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <release>10</release>
        <!-- or 11 -->
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

これが無いので、MavenがJava 10以降でコンパイルしないために、そのエラーが出ているのではないかと思います。

Comment: 答えて下さいまして、誠にありがとうございます。mavenの規定コンパイラーはJava 11ではなく、Java 10 ではありませんね。